# SQL query update conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables

```
aaa
on_date datetime null,
channel_id numeric(10,0) null,
type_id  numeric(10,0) null,
amount numeric(10,0) null

bbb
channel_id  numeric(10,0) null
type_id numeric(10,0) null
```

I want to do an update to **aaa.amount** to 0 of

1. only the common channel_ids and type_ids when bbb.type_id is not
   null

**or**

2. of only the common channel_ids and ALL the type_ids when the
   bbb.type_id is null

   aaa

   2014-09-13 1  3  12

   2014-09-13 1  4  16

   2014-09-13 2  1  11

   bbb (case 1. )

   1  3

   bbb (case 2. )

   1  null

In first case only the first aaa record should have amount = 0
In the second case the first 2 records of aaa should have amount = 0 
Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
update a
set a.amount=0
from aaa a inner join bbb b 
on a.channel_id=b.channel_id
where ((a.channel_id=b.channel_id and a.type_id=b.type_id and b.type_id IS NOT NULL)
OR (a.channel_id=b.channel_id and b.type_id IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to somthing like following as per i understand your question

```
UPDATE
    aa
SET
    aa.amount  = 0 
FROM
    aaa aa
    JOIN
    bbb bb ON aa.channel_id  =bb.channel_id      
WHERE
    (aa.type_id = bb.type_id AND bb.type_id is not null ) 
    OR
    (bb.type_id is null)
```

Hope it will help to you.